# How to use rememberPagerState in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opLl9.png)

````
   ```val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
      ) {
        // provide pageCount
     }```
````

What should I provide in body of rememberPagerState i.e in place of provide pageCount.

I have pass pagerCount also as paramter but it give error again.

Moreover I use ScrollableTabRow in my Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass number of pages :D

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f,
        pageCount = { 10 }
      )
```

Last argument is lambda so AS add it like a body for compose function. Just return total amount of pages here. Most propably it will be something like this `pageCount = { itemsList.size }`.

Comment: Material3 has made changes In Pager API

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem by providing pagerCount value.
Provide the number according to your the required categories of Row.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
    7
})
```